# Glide cannot find package "." in

Tags: go, glide-golang

My project tree is `$GOPATH/src/gillab.myfirm.ru/golang/rkn`

I try to use glide for get dependency `glide install` and I am stuck with a problem:

```
[ERROR] Error scanning gitlab.myfirm.ru/golang/rkn/events: cannot find package "." in:
    /Users/droot/.glide/cache/src/https-gitlab.myfirm.ru-golang-rkn/events
```

I don't understand what exactly glide want from me.  What such package is this `"."` ?

`$GOPATH/src/gitlab.myfirm.ru/golang/rkn/event/events.go` have only 4 imports

```
package events

import (
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
    "fmt"
    "gitlab.myfirm.ru/golang/rkn/config"
)
........
```

same problem I got with another 4 packages.

Comment: Is there any other file in `$GOPATH/src/gitlab.myfirm.ru/golang/rkn/event` besides `events.go` ? What happens if you remove `/Users/droot/.glide/cache/src/https-gitlab.myfirm.ru-golang-rkn/events` ?

Comment: nope only events.go, use `glide cc` (clear cache) same result

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer.

When glide makes cache files, git is in there.

If `master` have `foo package` and `someBranch` have also `bar package` when you make `glide install` glide also cache git branches and give from cache `master` branch as default.

The solution is `cd /Users/droot/.glide/cache/src/https-gitlab.myfirm.ru-golang-‌​rkn/` and checkout cache branch `git checkout someBranch`

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this error can occur when your Go code attempts to import a package which does not exist in Github or no longer exists.

For example, it used to be that the package `github.com/hashicorp/terraformbuiltin/providers/aws`  existed:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/v0.9.6/builtin/providers

But as of Terraform 0.11, it has been moved: 
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/v0.11.2/builtin/providers
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws